# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when returning UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiimage, exc-bad-access

I have a method which should return a UIImage created from contentsOfFile (to avoid caching), but when it returns, i receive EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Running through Instruments doesn't reveal any results, as it just runs, without stopping on a zombie.

The image is correctly copied in the Bundle Resources phase...

```
- (UIImage *)imageForName:(NSString *)name {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"png"];
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

}

This method was adapted from the PhotoScroller sample, which works correctly.

Thanks

EDIT:

This is the code that uses imageForName, and you can see i added the retain, as per Luke/T's suggestion, but the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is on the return, not my addObject: call:

```
NSMutableArray *images;

for (NSDictionary *dict in imageListForPage){
    [images addObject:[[self imageForName:[dict valueForKey:@"name"]]retain]];
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code that uses imageForName, see Luke's answer

Answer (score 2):

ImageWithContentsOfFile will return an auto-released object. If you are not retaining it (on return [edit]) then you will get a bad access.

Edit:

Check the pointer of the NSarray. You need to init the Array either `alloc` as normal or use the `arraywith`

e.g.

```
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:ARRAY_CAPACITY];//autoreleased
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];//release later
```

Comment: Don't retain it in `imageForName:` itself, though.

Comment: I altered the code, above, to show what happens when i did this. It's as if the image cant be found, but im not getting nil.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an object to an `NSMutableArray` will implicitly send it a `retain`, so that's not necessary in your code.

Can you confirm (using `NSLog()` or a breakpoint) that

`[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]`

returns an object in your `imageForName:` method?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this code should be:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray new]; // new is same as [[alloc] init]

for (NSDictionary *dict in imageListForPage) {
  [images addObject:[self imageForName:[dict valueForKey:@"name"]]];
}
// ... do something with images
[images release];
```